# Remove Ip From Ip and domain restriction through powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, windows-server-2012

I am able to add IP in the IIS IP and domain restriction list through powershell, but cant able to remove the IP from there.

**example:**

> add-WebConfiguration /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Location "iis:\default web site" -Value @{ipaddress="192.168.1.1";allowed="true"}

How can I remove the same ip from there through powershell

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same and this is working:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty /system.webServer/security/ipSecurity -location "iis:\default web site" -Name "." -AtElement @{ipAddress="192.168.1.1";allowed="true"} -PSPath IIS:\
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me on Windows 10 giving
    Property . is not found

Answer (score 0):

You could specify allowed = false, to effectively shut down this same rule.

```
add-WebConfiguration /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Locat "iis:\default web site" `
   -Value @{ipaddress="192.168.1.1";allowed="false"}
```

Comment: but when i try this, i got error like "Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with combined key attributes 'ipAddress, subnetMask, domainName' "

Comment: Sorry, the command should be Set-WebConfiguration instead, with those same params.  Give it a shot and let me know how it works!

Comment: when i try like set-WebConfiguration /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Locat "iis:\default web site" `
   -Value @{ipaddress="192.168.1.1";allowed="false"} am getting error "set-WebConfiguration : Key value is missing."

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove-WebConfiguration -Filter 'system.webserver/security/ipsecurity'-PSPath "iis:\" -Location "default website" -AtElement @{ipaddress="192.168.1.1";allowed="false";}
```

That did it for me (with a different location and address of course)