# Setting IP address and domain restrictions using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I am looking to automate deployment of a site.

Within this site there are some folders that I wish to enable IP Address and Domain Restrictions on. I have searched, however all the post that I can find show how to enable what I want to do, but using the IIS Manager GUI. I am trying to determine how to do this using Powershell.

I have a site, www-a.contoso.com, and within this site I have a folder called secure.

Within this secure folder, for the IP Address and Domain Restrictions I want to automate the following:

1. For Edit Feature Settings, set the access for Deny to an Deny Action Type of "Forbidden"
2. Add an allow entry for ip address 127.0.0.1

I only want to apply this to the secure folder and not the entire website.

I am trying to do this on Windows 2012 R2, with IIS 8.5

**UPDATE**

I have found that the following Powershell command will add in the allow ip address.

```
add-webconfiguration -filter /system.webServer/security/ipSecurity -location "www-a.contoso.com/secure" -value @{ipAddress="127.0.0.1";allowed="true"} -PSPath "IIS:\"
```

and be specified at the secure folder only, while not affecting the rest of the site.

However I still looking for Edit Feature Settings, set the access for Deny to an Deny Action Type of "Forbidden" for the secure folder

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331022/remove-ip-from-ip-and-domain-restriction-through-powershell?rq=1) to see if the answer there works for you?

Comment: I'm just looking for the same property name! Did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Many years later I imagine that you found the solution. Anyway I post what I finally could make work fine:

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "www-a.contoso.com/secure" -filter "system.webServer/security/ipSecurity" -name "allowUnlisted" -value "False"