# Remove Ip From Ip and domain restriction through powershell on iis

Tags: windows, iis-7, iis-6, powershell-4.0

How to remove ip and domain restrictions with powershell? I tried many references solution but i still cannot solve its. please help me,

References 1
[Remove Ip From Ip and domain restriction through powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331022/remove-ip-from-ip-and-domain-restriction-through-powershell)
references 2
https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/e32d7a33-0bf8-44c4-a162-dda21736d9d2/y

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to check the existing webconfig file to confirm the result of the modification.
File name: ApplicationHost.config
Location (IIS7 or higher version): %WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config

For the command below, I changed the location from your original which will not make any difference.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Name allowUnlisted -Value "true" -Location "IIS:\Sites\default web site"
```

According to the given image, you set the value to "true" for the property name "allowUnlisted" in the location "system.webserver/security/ipsecurity", which could be found there. The section would be

```
<system.webserver>
 <security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
  </ipSecurity>
 </security>
</system.webserver>
```

Then, if you want to change the last setting, you just need to modify the value to "false".
Command:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Name allowUnlisted -Value "false" -Location "IIS:\Sites\default web site"
```

The result would be:

```
<system.webserver>
     <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
      </ipSecurity>
     </security>
    </system.webserver>
```

For further usage of the command, you could read below example.

Command: Add allowed ip

```
add-WebConfiguration /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Location "iis:\default web site" -Value @{ipaddress="192.168.1.1";allowed="true"} -PSPath IIS:\
```

Result:

```
   <system.webserver>
     <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
        <add ipAddress="192.168.1.1" allowed="true" />
      </ipSecurity>
     </security>
    </system.webserver>
```

Command: Remove the allowed ip

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty /system.webServer/security/ipSecurity -location "iis:\default web site" -Name "." -AtElement @{ipAddress="192.168.1.1";allowed="true"}  -PSPath IIS:\
```

Result:

```
   <system.webserver>
     <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
      </ipSecurity>
     </security>
    </system.webserver>
```

Another way to remove it: Set allow from "true" to "false"
Command:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Name "." -AtElement @{ipAddress="192.168.1.1";allowed="true"} -Value @{ipAddress="192.168.1.1";allowed="false"} -Location "IIS:\Sites\default web site"
```

Result:

```
<system.webserver>
 <security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
    <add ipAddress="192.168.1.1" allowed="false" />
  </ipSecurity>
 </security>
</system.webserver>
```

Hope helps.